# Laravel 5 перенаправление после входа

Tags: laravel, url, redirect, laravel5

Здравствуйте. После входа, регистрации или выхода из сайта изменяется язык на сайте на стандартный, как сохранить языковую метку?

> app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

```
public function authenticated()
{
    if(auth()->user()->is_admin)
    {
        return redirect('/admin');
    }

    return redirect()->route('profile', ['id' => auth()->user()->id]);
}
```

> routes\web.php

```
Route::get('/profile', 'MypageController@register');
```

> app\Http\Controllers\MyPageController.php

```
public function register()
{
    return redirect()->route('profile', ['id' => auth()->user()->id]);
}
```

Comment: В вашем коде вообще не увидел хоть что-то про локализацию.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan, у меня в web.php прописано правило, что при переходе через `route()` должно переходить на страницу в зависимости от языка. Просто на страницах это работает, а при входе, регистрации и выходе почему то нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Храните метку в Cookie мой вам совет.